# Flask download video multiprocess

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, flask, python-requests

Estou fazendo um projecto de download de vídeos de um site e guarda em uma pasta no computador.
É o seguinte, tenho uma rota `@app.route('/baixar', methods=['POST'])` que é responsável por baixar vídeo e redirecionar o usuário.

Só que eu gostaria que usuário não esperasse até o vídeo baixar para ser redirecionado. Será que existe uma forma de fazer o download de baixo dos panos?

O código:

```
@app.route('/baixar', methods=['POST'])
def baixar():
    nome_video = request.args.get('nome_video')
    id_video = request.args.get('id_video')
    
    url_video = "url aqui"
    
    download_file(url_video, nome_video),

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Eu quero que o faça download sem travar o **flask**

Comment: Utilize o recurso asyncrono do próprio Python ou utilzie o Celery.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima pode me recomendar artigos sobre ansicronia no python? Já li sobre Celery só acho que é muita coisa para algo tão simples.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html